# Optimizing requests that requires several request

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-web-services, requests

I have a request that requires my server to establish like 3 external requests before it returns to the user. This makes this request takes like 0.8s to execute per user. What tips should one follow to optimize it so that the server can handle several requests per second? I use Apache+PHP+MySQL. Currently, on AWS micro machine, I can't handle even 5 requests per second!

Comment: Have you pinpointed where the time is spent? Is your app slow in processing the external results, or are the externals servers slow to respond. You need to measure before you can optimize.

Comment: Modify your service to not make external requests, or at least do some caching if possible, so that you don't have to perform them very often.

Comment: I think you are asking (in addition to speeding up the requests) how you can get Apache to handle more requests per second. On your t1.micro, you will max out memory much before you max out CPU for Apache requests. If possible, avoid mod_php (use php-fpm ideally, or mod_fcgi if that isn't possible) and if you don't need Apache try a lighter server (such as Nginx or lighttpd). Cache (memcached, redis, varnish, etc.) whatever you can (both requests and responses - if they aren't completely individual). Determine the per thread memory usage of Apache, and conservatively set the MaxServers.

Answer (score 1):

Much of your waiting I expect is spent actually *blocked* whilst responses come through. Doing this serially is not ideal.

You should parallelize. You can use `curl_multi_init` from the `php-curl` module to asynchronously connect back to your data stores.

This doesn't fix a underlying issue -- the remote datastores response speed is out of your control. But, then again you should be caching some of this content (you can use `memcache` for that if you wanted) even if it becomes stale in a minute or two.